# gem5 build error config_embedded_python.<locals>.flag_filter() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were give

Tags: gem5

I am trying to install gem5 on a macos M2 and use 1d03f6de941520860c673b5f7954c82a46e8b191
when I try use
scons build/NULL/gem5.opt -j 5
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Mkdir("/Users/liyang/YangL/gem5/build/NULL/gem5.build")
Checking for linker -Wl,--as-needed support... no
Checking for compiler -Wno-c99-designator support... yes
Checking for compiler -Wno-defaulted-function-deleted support... yes
Checking for compiler -gz support... yes
Checking for linker -gz support... yes
Info: Using Python config: python3-config
TypeError: config_embedded_python..flag_filter() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given:
File "/Users/liyang/YangL/gem5/SConstruct", line 530:
config_embedded_python(env)
File "/Users/liyang/YangL/gem5/SConstruct", line 329:
env.ParseConfig(cmd, flag_filter)
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/scons/4.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/SCons/Environment.py", line 1674:
return function(self, self.backtick(command), unique)
make: *** [run] Error 2
I can not build success
I am not sure how to fix this error or even why this error is occurring; I don't even really know what this error is saying. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error. It was due to two different versions of scons on my system. By default, gem5 was running with the latest version of scons i.e., 4.4.0 present in the home/.local. Using version 3.1.2 present in /usr/bin/scons fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that the flag_filter function is being given 3 arguments, but it is only expecting 2. Not sure why that is happening, but you could try downgrading to scons 3.0.1.